# Insert emoji into DIV at cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was using the Jquery emoji to insert the emoji in DIV(not in textarea or textbox),but seems it has some problem that, the cursor position has always change when I click somewhere else,actually it should be stay at the end of Div when I click other place all the time,so how to fix that?
here s the Html:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" aria-placeholder="add something..."> 
</div>

<div class="m-t-70">
    <button class="btn btn-primary m-t-70" id="btnLoad2" >
        add or not whatever
    </button>
</div>
```

and part of js:

```
if ("DIV" === a.nodeName) {
    if (a.focus(),
        b.getSelection) {
        if (f = b.getSelection(),
            f.getRangeAt && f.rangeCount) {
            g = f.getRangeAt(0),
                g.deleteContents();
            var h = c.createElement("div");
            h.innerHTML = d;
            for (var i, j, k = c.createDocumentFragment();
                i = h.firstChild;)j = k.appendChild(i);
            var l = k.firstChild;
            g.insertNode(k),
                j && (g = g.cloneRange(),
                    g.setStartAfter(j),
                    e ? g.setStartBefore(l) : g.collapse(!0),
                    f.removeAllRanges(),
                    f.addRange(g))
        }
    }
    else if ((f = c.selection) && "Control" !== f.type) {
        var m = f.createRange();
        m.collapse(!0),
            f.createRange().pasteHTML(html),
            e && (g = f.createRange(),
                g.setEndPoint("StartToStart", m),
                g.select())
    }
}
else if (c.selection) a.focus(),
    f = c.selection.createRange(),
    f.text = d,
    f.select();
else if (a.selectionStart || 0 === a.selectionStart) {
    var n = a.selectionStart,
        o = a.selectionEnd,
        p = a.scrollTop;
    a.value = a.value.substring(0, n) + d + a.value.substring(o, a.value.length),
        p > 0 && (a.scrollTop = p),
        a.focus(),
        a.selectionStart = n + d.length,
        a.selectionEnd = n + d.length
}
else a.value += d,
    a.focus()
},
```

Comment: can you share an online demo?

Comment: @Kevin: can you share online demo it may get an better idea.

Comment: @pedram   yeah, sure, but that is in Chinese,http://eshengsky.github.io/jQuery-emoji/

Comment: Here is the online demo, you can see that the second one is for using the Div to insert the emoji,http://eshengsky.github.io/jQuery-emoji/

Comment: you can make and onlick on the div and save the cursor position at that moment into a variable.

Comment: @user5014677 first time to doing this, could you show me some tips for it?

Comment: I just give you the idea. that's why i'm answering in comments i don't want to write the code :p you just do `$(".yourdivclass/id").click(function(){ myselection = window.getSelection();});` You define a myselection globally and use it in your button function. You can also try to set your div to contenteditable maybe it will work idk

Comment: @user5014677 why should he do this? What if the user navigates by the left, right keys after that click? Or never clicks? It's ok to read out the position in the moment you need the position.

Comment: @JoshuaK You clear it aftre using the selection if your selection is nothing you add at the end. Use onkeypress what ever. This is an idea it's not an answer. Welcome to comment section. his current code is overexcessive anyway. I'm just giving a simple idea how to do it following the description of his problem. If you have a better option you're free to add it.

Comment: @Kevin the div is not editable in your example. so please specify how the user should place the cursor in it. I cannot place my cursor within a not editable div element.

Comment: @user5014677 it looks more simply, I'like to try it first , and see if there s some additional issues,thank you anyway XD.

Comment: @Joshua K you can see that editable DIV in my HTML , it s definitely can place the cursor in it ,u were jus miss some js code I think  , pls see the demo what I gave above.

Comment: @Kevin I can rebuild the example without any problems: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/fsj915wg/). Please update the fiddle with your code to show us where you stuggle or what your problem is.

Comment: @ Joshua K Here is the code:https://jsfiddle.net/fsj915wg/2/  the thing is : The DIV couldn't save the position of cursor when I type something in DIV,It should be stay at the end of content.

Comment: @ Joshua  if you try to insert more emoji in DIV you ll see the problem clearly.

Comment: @kevin alright. I can reproduce it sometimes. it happens, when the div loses focus before the emoji is inserted. you could fix this by saving the position on keyup and click. Or open a ticket at the developer site of the plugin

Comment: @ Joshua  I'll try it that later , thank you for your advice anyway.